# Can Bash Tell Me Which SSH Public Key Was Used To Authenticate?

Tags: bash, ssh-keys

Let's say I want to track my `root` users. Each of them has a unique private key and their public keys have been stored in `/root/.ssh/authorized_keys`.

Given that each user logs in with their unique key how can I tell from within a BASH session which key was used to authenticate? I've tried looking at the environment variables when I log in but cannot see anything that correlates my session with my public key.

Comment: Slightly related: setting LogLevel VERBOSE in your (openssh) sshd_config will log the fingerprint of the key used to login.

Answer (score 21):

You could add the username to the public key in `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` on the server and export it as an environment value:

```
environment="REALUSER=realusername" ssh-dsa AAA...
```

That will set the environment variable REALUSER which will then be available to use in bash. This will only work if `PermitUserEnvironment` is set to true in `sshd_config`

Comment: Whoah.. really? Cool! You mean in `~/.ssh/authorized_keys`? I never knew about this.

Comment: Yep, that's it. You can do a whole lot of interesting things there - `man ssh` will tell you more under the heading `AUTHORIZED_KEYS FILE FORMAT`.

Comment: It might depend on the version, but I had to use `man sshd` to find the `AUTHORIZED_KEYS FILE FORMAT` section.

Comment: Be aware that enabling PermitUserEnvironment has some security implications. Read man sshd